# Understanding flex-basis in flex shorthand

Tags: css, flexbox

I understand flex-grow: it allows a flex item to grow based on a ratio relative to the other flex items on the same row/column.

I understand flex-shrink: it allows a flex item to shrink based on a ratio relative to the other flex items on the same row/column.

I understand flex-basis: it overrules the main-size value and sets it's width (or height, depending on orientation).

However, I don't understand `flex-basis: auto || 0` and the like.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one item">Box 1</div>
  <div class="two item">Box 2</div>
  <div class="three item">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.one {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}

.two {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.three {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

I expected that all three boxes would be the same size, since they all are set to `flex-grow: 1`. However, not only is this not the case, Box one is bigger than either box *and* larger than 100px.

What is making the sizes be uneven despite the even ratio of flex-grow and the flex-basis of box 1 to be ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an instance of "relative flex": The `flex-basis` of each flex item is used, and the remaining space is added to these.

`100px` just happens to be larger than the `auto` of the other two in your example; available space is added evenly to all boxes after taking the `flex-basis` into account.

This is what happens when box two has a larger intrinsic width than the 100px of box 1: http://jsbin.com/gakeju/1/

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis

(Not your question, but to clarify: if you want the items to have space distributed to them without accounting for their (intrinsic) width, then you should set flex-basis to 0 (or 0%), i.e. `flex: 1 0 0;`. This would make the items *in your example* the same width, since all the boxes start with the same `flex-basis` and then get the space distributed to them.)

Comment: "100px just happens to be larger than the auto of the other two in your example; available space is added evenly to all boxes after taking the flex-basis into account."  This was key for me. Thanks. I knew it couldn't be too complicated but I learn by fiddling around with properties and value and this one had me stumped! I had seen that page on w3 and the picture and I thought it might be related, but I just couldn't wrap my mind around it. Thank you!